# Disk performance improvement program

Tags: windows, hard-disk

I often copy large amount of data from network computer to my computer and when I do my computer gets slowed down, I can't open my programs for minutes because of copying.
I found program [AMD RADEON RAMDISK](http://www.radeonramdisk.com/software_downloads.php) but I'm not happy with how it works because I need to set size of a disk right away and can't copy files larger than that size (FREEWARE-Up to 4GB and my RAM is 4GB so I can set small disk), have to copy to RAMDISK first then on disk(again to disk on shutdown=problem not solved)

Intel has a solution that works like I want but I don't have Intel Board nor SSD It's called [Intel Smart Response Technology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgYPk2j5PNM).

μTorrent has option to override disk cache and use RAM and that's exactly what I need, except to set this option in Explorer.

Is there a program that can increase disk cache of my disk when writing data to it?